# Biggest distance between different points based on x-values and y-values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math, distance

I got a bunch of nodes which are stored in an array `arr`.
Each node has a x and y value which repesents the position on the screen.
Now, i created the middle element of `arr` and save it in `middle`.
Now, my goal is, to find out the distance between `middle` and all other nodes and also find out the one with the maximum distance. For the distance I use the Pythagorean theorem `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`, that means `sqrt(a^2 + b^2) = c` or in my case `sqrt(x^2 + y^2) = distance between 2 nodes`.

For example to create the distance between `(10,10)` and `(20,30)` I create the difference  of the x-scale and the y-scale, that means `x = 20-10 = 10` and `y = 30-10 = 20`. The result is, that the distance between those nodes is `sqrt( 10^2 + 20^2) = 22,3.` In my code, I check with the `if-loop`, which x-value and y-value is bigger to avoid negative values. But something I made is wrong. Maybe someone can help?

```
    var middle = arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];
    var arrayForDistance = [];
    var distance = [];
    for(i = 0; i != arr[middle] & i< arr.length;  i++ ) {

     if(arr[i].x > arr[middle].x) { 

    var newX = arr[i].x - arr[middle].x;
    var newY = arr[i].y - arr[middle].y;
    } 

else if ( arr[i].x < arr[middle].x)
      {
    var newX = arr[middle].x - arr[i].x;
    var newY = arr[middle].y - arr[i].y;
    }}


    distance = sqrt( newX^2 + newY^2)
    arrayForDistance.push(distance[i]);
    }

    var maxDistance = Math.max.apply(null, arrayForDistance)
```

Comment: The problem is `i != arr[middle]` - it causes the loop to break, so you aren't looping through elements after `middle`. Place it in the for loop body instead, e.g. `if (i == middle) continue`. (and anyway it should be `i != middle` in the first place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you dont need to worry about negatives since you are squareing them, they will cancel out.

secondly your for loop is wrong  it should be

```
var middle = arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];
var arrayForDistance = [];
var distance ;
for(i = 0;  i< arr.length;  i++ ) {

    if (i != Math.floor(arr.length / 2)){
    var newX = arr[i].x - arr[middle].x;
    var newY = arr[i].y - arr[middle].y;

    distance = sqrt( newX^2 + newY^2)
    arrayForDistance.push(distance);
   }
}
var maxDistance = Math.max.apply(null, arrayForDistance)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why this error? "arr[middle] is not defined"

Comment: the only way i could see that happening is if arr isn't defined outside of this code block (as its not defined in it)

Comment: Strange. When i put in   `console.log(arr)`  it gives me `Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]`. `console.log(middle)` gives me and object with attributes. but `console.log(arr[middle])` is undefined.

Comment: OOHHH. you can't use an object like that as a key to an array. you are going to want to replace all of your `arr[middle]` with `arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)]` or put `Math.floor(arr.length / 2)` into a variable and use that

Comment: oh, i found the error. istead of `arr[middle].x` it has to be `middle.x`.

Comment: also `sqrt()` does not work, it has to be `Math.sqrt()`

Comment: also note i made an edit to the if statement. as it actually would not have worked

Comment: Yeah, i just put `console.log(arrayForDistance)` and it gives me  `Array [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`. Do you knw what is the problem?

Comment: you were using an array like a regular object i edited my code, it should fix it

Comment: oh, wow. The problem was that distance[i] was totally wrong. Thanks so much for your help!